# Get value from mpfr generated list

Tags: r

Considering the following vector :

```
> v1
[1] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.110223e-16 4.440892e-15 3.266195e-08 2.531242e-07   
1.041204e-05 1.172329e-05 1.672447e-05 1.803203e-05
```

I have applied mpfr from function (from the Rmpfr package)to v1 :

```
> v2<-sapply(v1,function(x){mpfr(x,5)})
```

v2 is apparently a list, but I cannot get the actual value. I have tried using unlist, v2[[]], converting to character v2[[]] or vector..

```
> v2

[[1]]
'mpfr1' 0

[[2]]
'mpfr1' 0

[[3]]
 'mpfr1' 1.11e-16
```

Comment: look at the output of `str(v2)` using `sapply()` to see all the gory details of what is returned.

Answer (score 5):

Actually I had a similar problem, since this is the first time I am using this package. Anyway, I have found a simple solution, albeit not the most elegant, I may add...:

```
   # Compute 1/7 with 1000 bit precision and store the value in a character object
   x <- mpfr(1,1000)/7
   x.output <- capture.output(x)[2]
   result <- substr(x.output,5,nchar(x.output))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use `str()` with options `give.head=FALSE` and `digits.d`.

```
> x<-mpfr(1,120)/7

> x    #This would print the precision info
1 'mpfr' number of precision  120   bits
[1] 0.14285714285714285714285714285714285722

> str(x, give.head=FALSE, digits.d=10)
0.1428571429
```

If you want to store this string, you need `capture.output()`:

```
> y<-capture.output(str(x, give.head=FALSE, digits.d=10))
> y
[1] "0.1428571429"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need `sapply()` here at all, you can simply pass in a vector:

```
require(Rmpfr)
v1 <- c(0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 1.110223e-16, 4.440892e-15, 3.266195e-08, 2.531242e-07)
v2 <- mpfr(v1,5)
#-----
> v2
6 'mpfr' numbers of precision  5   bits 
[1]        0        0 1.11e-16 4.44e-15  3.35e-8  2.53e-7
```

As a caveat, I've never used this package or function before, so I recommend a thorough reading of `?mpfr` to ensure you're up to speed on the arguments and their implications.

Comment: I have used sapply because the function was part of a function I was applying to that vector and I was only getting errors there..I don't think that the help page for this package is enough though, in this case..Thanks

Comment: I still cannot get the actual value from that vector, if you type v2[1] : 1 mpfr number of precision 5 bits  [1] 0

Comment: @agatha - what are you trying to do with the actual value that you can't do? Are you sure it's not just a format/printing thing? For example, multiplying that vector by `pi` seems to give reasonable results: `> v2 * pi
6 'mpfr' numbers of precision  5   bits 
[1]        0        0 3.47e-16 1.38e-14  1.04e-7  8.05e-7`

Comment: because I need this formatted value to print it out as it is in a html generated report. what else do you use for approximating real numbers with a certain amount of digits that wouldn't round the really small, close values to the same number?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
x <- 2*Rmpfr::pnorm(mpfr((1.0490/0.0246), precBits=100), lower.tail=FALSE, log.p = FALSE)

1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
[1] 2.6253807992339014869315885783658e-397

sub("\'mpfr1\' ", "", capture.output(x@.Data[[1]]))
[1] "2.6253807992339014869315885783658e-397"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a method in the `Rmpfr` package that deals with converting from `mpfr` type to numeric, called `asNumeric`. You can use it in combination with `sapply` as suggested in other answers.

```
v1 <- c(0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 1.110223e-16, 4.440892e-15, 3.266195e-08, 2.531242e-07, 1.041204e-05, 1.172329e-05, 1.672447e-05, 1.803203e-05)
v2 <- sapply(v1,function(x){mpfr(x,5)})

v2_numeric <- sapply(v2, asNumeric)
v2_numeric
```

Output:

```
 [1] 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.110223e-16 4.440892e-15 3.352761e-08 2.533197e-07 1.049042e-05 1.192093e-05 1.716614e-05
[10] 1.811981e-05
```